# is what i'm trying to do with ob_start() possible?

Tags: php, include, ob-start

I'm new to php and trying to create a simple script.. but I don't know if what i'm trying to do is possible with ob_start() please let me know, thanks.
here is my code:

```
<?php
ob_start();

if($mystuff !== 0) { foreach($mystuff['sirf7alk'] as $mystuff) {
?>

<?php include('header.php'); ?>

App name: <?php echo $mystuff->app; ?>

<?php include('footer.php');?>

<?php
} } 

file_put_contents('page.php', ob_get_contents());
?>
```

that's what my code outputs:

```
my header content
App name: My app name
my footer content
```

here is what i want to achieve:

```
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
App name: My app name
<?php include('footer.php');?>
```

Comment: Why do you want to write to `page.php` in that process? Is that to be invoked on a second request? Are you trying to update multiple pages that way, or just that one?

Comment: I'm trying to create many pages but I want to use same header/footer in all pages.

Comment: Commonly advised at this point is to utilize a database for those pages. It's much more maintainable to have a handler/template script for mixing page layout and content. Having dozens of pageXYZ.php copies gets unwieldy fast.

Comment: Yes I did think about creating a database, but as I motioned I'm new to php and this was easier for me because the data that I need to store is long text (descriptions, long links etc..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
ob_start();

if($mystuff !== 0) { foreach($mystuff['sirf7alk'] as $mystuff) {

echo "<?php include('header.php'); ?>\n";
?>
App name: <?php echo $mystuff->app; ?>

<?php
echo "<?php include('footer.php');?>\n";

} } 

file_put_contents('page.php', ob_get_contents());
?>
```

Should do it. You must echo the whole include lines as strings to avoid php from parsing it

Answer (score 3):

You need to *output* the PHP code, as opposed to *running* it. Treating it as a string will do that:

```
ob_start();
if ($mystuff !== 0) {
    foreach($mystuff['sirf7alk'] as $mystuff) {
        echo "<?php include 'header.php' ?>".PHP_EOL;
        echo "App name: {$mystuff->app}".PHP_EOL;
        echo "<?php include 'footer.php' ?>".PHP_EOL;
    }
}
$output = ob_get_contents();
file_put_contents('page.php', $output);
```

Now that the actual question is answered... It may be fun to control output buffering in this way, but it is probably not the best idea in the world, which is to say that there are better ways of achieving the same result. E.g. simply using an auxiliary variable, which holds the otherwise output buffered content, is a much saner approach:

```
$output = '';
if ($mystuff !== 0) {
    foreach($mystuff['sirf7alk'] as $mystuff) {
        $output .= "<?php include 'header.php' ?>".PHP_EOL;
        $output .= "App name: {$mystuff->app}".PHP_EOL;
        $output .= "<?php include 'footer.php' ?>".PHP_EOL;
    }
}
file_put_contents('page.php', $output);
```